# Accessing Applications

Tags: gnome

Color me stupid, but I've read and tried to execute the suggestions here for this issue and have failed.

All I want to do is find and then execute the applications available, the ones I see are already installed. I get it that there are two ways to do this, but I need a simpler instruction than the ones I've seen here -- no offence to the generous souls who provided that advice.

To be specific, I'd like to use Audio Recorder. I know it's installed because I can bring up the window that shows me that. But how do I get it to run? And how can I do the same for the other apps that are also installed?

Thanks.

Comment: Not every "application" has a graphical interface, there are a large number of applications that are command line only.

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to know how to get to them.

Comment: you have to be a lot more specific then that. you get them using apt-get or software center. See the Ubuntu documentation - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: @Tom see my answer, it should help your situation, if I've understood right.

Comment: Is your desktop Unity?

Answer (score 1):

Open the dash by pressing the windows key. Type `Audio Recorder`, or whatever the name of the app is. Press enter, or use the mouse to select it. It should open.

Comment: I am not sure, but the tag `gnome` might indicate a non-Unity desktop :)

Comment: Maybe, but `gnome` still uses the super key. And they haven't specified. I find a lot of people using `gnome` because they think that is what ubuntu uses, and they can't be bothered to add one that is relevant.

Comment: That brings up the Recent Apps window, including MusicBox and a few others, but not Audio Recorder, though it did show up as an installed app when I last looked.

Comment: Did you search for it?

Comment: I did. But I'll reinstall it if necessary. In any case, I'm downloading Audacity, which will do the job. Thanks very much for your help, Tim. I'll keep you posted. -Tom

Comment: That's okay. You shouldn't need to reinstall, but audacity definitely will appear in the search.